# Having Issues while upload the doc and pdf file on dropbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Problem: I have use the net/http code for uploading the '.doc', '.docx', '.pdf' and images files on dropbox. But I getting the issues like:

1. invalid byte sequence in UTF 8.
2. Now while the file is uploading but it not uploading the content and even it uploading as a corrupt file.

Below I writing my code to upload the file on dropbox. Please help me.

Code:

```
      uri = URI.parse("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload")
      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri)
      request.content_type = "application/octet-stream"
      request["Authorization"] = "Bearer #{$acess_token}"
      request["Dropbox-Api-Arg"] = "{\"path\":\"/Sass-for-Web-Designers.pdf\"}"
      request.body = ""
      request.body << File.open("app/assets/images/categoryImages/Sass-for-Web-Designers.pdf").read
        #request.body << file.content
        #file.close
      #end
      req_options = {
        use_ssl: uri.scheme == "https",
      }
      response = Net::HTTP.start(uri.hostname, uri.port, req_options) do |http|
        http.request(request)
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. It just because the file is reading in text format not binary. Below the line updated in above code

```
  request.body <<  File.open("app/assets/images/categoryImages/Sass-for-Web-Designers.pdf", 'rb').read
```

thanks